# MVC 3 Video.Flash helper not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to use the Video helper to show a flash video on a site I'm working on but nothing is showing. I tried the MediaPlayer helper and that worked fine, I've loaded up the flash video I'm trying to play in a media player on my machine and it loads and plays. I've gone right back to basics and just entered the path into the helper but still no joy. Here is the code in my view:

```
<h2>Movies</h2>

@Video.Flash(path: @Url.Content("~/Media/07477279-df26-4a6e-895a-2ead51d90d21.flv"))
```

When I looked at the HTML generated there is a  there but nothing is loading. I'm stumped! Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Is it a custom Video helper? Can I see the code of it?

Comment: I think this helper is part of http://nuget.org/packages/microsoft-web-helpers

Comment: In the description of the package is written "This package is not compatible with ASP.NET". So I guess this works only on Web Pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to use a url of a flash file (.swf) rather than the direct url to an flv, and then the flash file plays the flv.

Comment: Please is there an example of where to get the url for the flash file?